# Is it possible to get accepted in RISS CMU with low CGPA?

Tags: internship

I'm a student in Birla Institute of Technology & Science (BITS), Pilani, India and am starting my 3rd year. My GPA is as low as 5.5/10 and I don't expect it to improve much by the end of 3rd year. I have done a lot of robotics projects and hope to publish a paper this year (not in robotics though).

What are the chances of me getting accepted in the Carnegie Mellon University (CMU) Robotics Institute Summer Scholars (RISS) program? Please tell the truth out bluntly. Also if there is any chance that I can get accepted by doing something please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

On their website it says, "RISS is among the best and most comprehensive robotics research programs for undergraduates in the world." This should not deter you from applying but I would advise that you strongly apply yourself in raising your GPA, if that is at all possible.

The first filter for rejecting applications of any type is often based on the language used in the applications. It needs to say, "I am serious about my work. I am dedicated and focused. I make the effort to do a good job." by setting the right tone with the formatting, grammar and language style (and not by explicitly saying, "*I am serious ...*").

Comment: Also, note that it is very competitive, with a lot of applications. If there is nothing to make a candidate stand out from the crowd it will be very difficult under these conditions. However, if you don't apply you are assured that you won't be accepted. +1